# Issues with While looping with generic dialog box in Jython - Image J

Tags: python, while-loop, jython, imagej

I am trying to write a code so that it repeats a series of commands in Image J until the user is satisfied with the results. This is what I tried:

```
from ij.gui import NonBlockingGenericDialog

num = True
while num is True:  
    #a series of a commands will go here
    dia2 = NonBlockingGenericDialog("Better")
    dia2.addMessage("does that look good?")
    dia2.showDialog()
    if dia2.wasCanceled:
        rm.reset()
            num = True
            print num
    elif dia2.wasOKed:
        print "background good"
        num = False
        break
```

The issue is that the script stays in the loop even if the dialog box was OKed, thus creating an infinite loop. I'm not sure how to format this to properly break the loop when necessary.

Comment: You should explain better what is the problem that you are experiencing

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize how vague I mad the post. Basically this while loop will not break when the dialog box is ok, and enters and infinite loop